# Display custom labels on X-axis with Rickshaw JS library

Tags: javascript, charts, rickshaw

I have a dataset with pairs `{x: someValue, y: count}` where `someValue` is a day of the week in a form of (`1..7`) where `1` is *"Sunday"*.
On the Ricskshaw chart I would like to display (*Mon*, *Tue*..etc) respectively on the X-axis. How do I do that?

At the moment I have done:

```
var ticksTreatment = 'glow';
var xAxisQPerDay = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time( {
          graph: graphQPerDay,
          ticksTreatment: ticksTreatment
      } );
xAxisQPerDay.render();
```

but this gives me, of course, the default values 1s, 2s, 3s etc...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var xAxisQPerDay = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
    graph: graphQPerDay,
    tickFormat: function(x) {
        switch (x) {
            case 1: return 'Mon';
            case 2: return 'Tue';
            case 3: return 'Wed';
            case 4: return 'Thu';
            case 5: return 'Fri';
            case 6: return 'Sat';
            case 7: return 'Sun';
        }
    }
});

xAxisQPerDay.render();
```

---

A more dynamic approach if you have built a map on the side to cache the field data.

```
var days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
var xAxisQPerDay = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
    graph: graphQPerDay,
    tickFormat: function(x) {
        return days[x];
    }
});

xAxisQPerDay.render();
```

*OR*

```
var days = { 0: 'Mon', 1: 'Tue', 2: 'Wed', 3: 'Thu', 4: 'Fri', 5: 'Sat', 6: 'Sun' };
var xAxisQPerDay = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
    graph: graphQPerDay,
    tickFormat: function(x) {
        return days[x];
    }
});

xAxisQPerDay.render();
```

Comment: it's better to keep a reference to the 'tickFormat' function because it can be used by other objects for eg `HoverDetail.xFormatter`